# metaio Augmented Reality tutorial

Tags: augmented-reality

I am new to Augmented Reality application development.I want to develop Android Application using Metaio SDK,but I am not getting any information about AR development using metaio.Please suggest me some tutorials on AR application development using Metaio SDK

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at official [Getting Started](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/) and [Tutorials](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/hello-world/). The SDK installer includes examples and templates for each supported platform.